# Создание хоткея на левую кнопку мыши

Tags: python

Как можно сделать хоткей на левую кнопки мышки в `pynput`? 
Что бы при нажатии левой кнопки мыши выводилось допустим `HelloWorld`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
from pynput import mouse

# Создаем обработчик события нажатия кнопки мыши
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed and button == mouse.Button.left:
        print('HelloWorld')

    if not pressed:
        # Если кнопка мыши отпущена, останавливаем обработчик
        return False

# Начинаем слушать события от мыши
with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Документацию можно найти [здесь](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).